# Understanding Scala type inference and extensial types

Tags: scala, types

In have the following class:

```
class MyClass[T <: Enum[T]](val clazz: Class[T]){
  def dummy = println(clazz.toString)
}
```

and method

```
def createMyClass(clazz: Class[_]) =
  if(clazz.isEnum)
    new MyClass(clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[Enum[T] forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }]]) //error
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

But it refuses to compile although `Enum[T]` satisfy the type constraint `T <: Enum[T]`. It works if I write `Class[T forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }]` though.

But why doesn't it work for the first case?

Answer (score 2):

So just to double check I understand the issue:

This works:

```
def createMyClass(clazz: Class[_]) =
    if(clazz.isEnum)
        new MyClass(clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[T forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }]])
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

This doesn't:

```
def createMyClass(clazz: Class[_]) =
    if(clazz.isEnum)
        new MyClass(clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[Enum[T] forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }]]) 
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

This is because the types don't line up. MyClass needs a 'T where T is a subclass of Enum[T]'. You're passing in an 'Enum[T] where T is a subclass of Enum[T]'. If you defined MyClass as the following for example then then which one works swaps round:

```
class MyClass[T <: Enum[T]](val clazz: Class[Enum[T]]){
    def dummy = println(clazz.toString)
}
```